# return trailing set of nums from string python

Tags: python, string, list, trailing

How can I return the trailing set of numbers from a list of strings?

```
mylist = ['kys_q1a2','kys_q3a20','kys_q2889b244','sonyps3_q92c288888']
```

**expected result:**

```
[2, 20, 244, 288888]
```

**My failed attempt:**

```
for item in mylist:
    print item[-1]
```

**Context:**

Each item in the list represents question name and consist of 2 parts:

1. question name and number: "kys_q1"
2. question element name and number: "a2"

I've tried to show the various ways they can be shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'\d+$')
>>> [int(m.group()) for m in (r.search(item) for item in mylist) if m]
[2, 20, 244, 288888]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex to match the trailing number:

```
>>> mylist = ['kys_q1a2','kys_q3a20','kys_q2889b244','sonyps3_q92c288888']
>>> [int(re.search(r'\d+$', el).group(0)) for el in mylist]
[2, 20, 244, 288888]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [ int(re.findall('(\d+$)', x)[0]) for x in mylist ]
[2, 20, 244, 288888]
>>>
```